# Uninitialized value reported by valgrind when using std::make_shared and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have the following (overly simplified) example where valgrind complains about uninitialized memory:

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B() {}
};
struct BB : public virtual B {
  virtual ~BB() = default;
};
struct BBB : public virtual B {
  virtual ~BBB() {}
};

struct X : public virtual B, public virtual BBB/*, public virtual BB*/ {
  X() { a = 0.0; b = 0.0; c = false;}
  double a;
  double b;
  bool c;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
auto y = std::make_shared<X>();
HexDump(y.get(), sizeof(X)); // simple hexdump function - similar to gtest output - in real application this is an "uninteresting mock call" where gtest prints binary representation of an object using its size
```

Working example here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91a54b697010d84b

Compiling this with gcc 4.9.2 c++14 flag and running through valgrind I get the following output:

```
==58887== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==58887==    at 0x93A065: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x95E2DA: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x9441DC: vsprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x93464C: sprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x100165310: HexDump(void*, unsigned int) (in xxxx)
==58887== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==58887==    at 0x93A69B: __ultoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x93A0CC: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x95E2DA: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x9441DC: vsprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x93464C: sprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==58887==    by 0x100165310: HexDump(void*, unsigned int) (in xxxxx)
```

Is this due to padding added by compiler at the end of the object (note the bool which "spans" 8 bytes) ? If so - what can be done for the check to not fail?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Emphasis on **complete** and **verifiable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is undefined behaviour as X is not a POD. Therefore it's illegal for you to start reading from random bytes in this fashion. If you want to dump the object, actually dump the object, and don't pretend that dumping the bytes is the same thing.

This is true regardless of if it's gmock doing the dumping instead of you.

Comment: As stated in the comment - this is a simplified version. What I have in real-world application is gtest reporting an uninteresting mock call and dumps the contents of the object.

Comment: @da_m_n: Then gmock is invoking the undefined behaviour and not you- but the principle is still the same. You can't pass this complex object to any function that randomly operates on bytes.